# WPF Data Binding to Dictionary in data object

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding

I have a USER data object which contain dictionary like this:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Dictionary<string, object> _metadata;

   public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata
    {
        get { return this._metadata; }
        set
        {
            this._metadata = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged("Metadata", value);
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property, object value)
    {           
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

I also have ViewModel consists of User data object like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{  
public static ViewModel getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ViewModel();
            return instance;
        }
private User _user;

public User User
        {
            get { return this._user; }
            set
            {
                this._user = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("User", value);
            }
        }
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property, object value)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
}
```

then in my main window, i do something to do data binding between the textbox and dictionary value (not the dictionary key ....)

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = ViewModel.getInstance().User.Metadata;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeDictonaryKey");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tb1, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding));
```

But it is not working, i tried different method on changing the  `binding.path` and `binding.source`, it is still not working....

Can anyone tell me what is the problem ????

Answer (score 3):

You can bind to the dictionary value by standard indexer syntax:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = ViewModel.getInstance().User;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Metadata[SomeDictonaryKey]");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tb1, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding));
```

Or you can use source to specify all path to the binding source:

```
myBinding.Source = ViewModel.getInstance().User.Metadata[SomeDictonaryKey];
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(".");
```

You can find more examples [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/binding-to-a-dictionary-in-wpf-and-silverlight).

Comment: great ! but the value is not changed when i change the textbox value.....seems like the Onpropertychange is not working ??

Comment: It should worked. You can see more examples [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/binding-to-a-dictionary-in-wpf-and-silverlight). How do you check changes? Where do you instantiate user in your view model? Are you sure that you have the same object when you are checking changes? Do you save changes?

Comment: I tried by binding two textboxes to the same dictionary key......it is not working...By right, the textbox should be changing the value when i change the other one's value....

Comment: No it should not because your dictionary indexer does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For this scenario you should use ObservableDictionary http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

Comment: Second textbox is not changed but data in dictionary actually changed.

Comment: wow!! it works!! why that one is not in the library of .Net framework ?

Comment: Huh I don't know ask @JohnSkeet :D

Comment: Have you actually tested the code from the second suggestion? I'm pretty sure that setting a two-way binding without `Path` or `XPath` specified will cause an `InvalidOperationException`...

Comment: @Grx70 oh you are totally right where the flag "great addition" button? I fixed my answer TY

Comment: @VadimMartynov you saved my life <3